# Mozilla Firefox radio button Issue

Tags: firefox, cross-browser, radio-button

I am developing a web application. I used radio buttons for selecting the category as shown in following image.

[image]

---

[image]

On Selecting the first radio button hides the Overlay button. On selecting the second radio button shows a button where on click of that i can select the data from overlay.

After clicking on second radio button, if i click on browsers refresh button the option2 is selected by default but the "select From Overlay" is not displayed. This issue is coming in Mozilla Firefox. Can anyone suggest how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value being preserved across the refresh is a convenience feature of forms. In this case, you will need some extra page init script to look at the value on the radio buttons to initialize as if the click happened.

Note: If you refresh with Ctrl+F5, you will generally see the browser will load the page with all the form values from before the refresh tossed out. Your user won't do this, but it illustrates how the browser is juggling your input in an effort to preserve it.

Comment: Thank you. I added the init script, to check the values while page load(or refresh), working correctly.